# Why is my program catching / throwing a FileNotFoundException when the file exists?

Tags: java, exception, runtime-error, filenotfoundexception

Java newbie here!

I'm writing a program to practice reading input and writing output to files.  I've finished coding the program, but when I run it, the program just catches and proceeds with a FileNotFoundException.

The file is in the source folder for the program, and I've even tried placing it in every folder related to the program.  I've tried:

- Declaring the exceptions in the method header
- Surrounding the section-in-question with a try/catch block.
- Both of the above together.

Here's the relevant code that is causing problems.  Is there something that sticks out that I'm missing?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String playerHighestScore = "", playerLowestScore = "";
    int numPlayers = 0, scoreHighest = 0, scoreLowest = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter an input file name: ");               
            String inputFileName = keyboard.nextLine();                 

    String outputFileName = getOutputFileName(keyboard, inputFileName);     
    File inputFile = new File(inputFileName);
    try {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(inputFile);
        reader.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {       
        System.out.println("There was a problem reading from the file.");                   
        System.exit(0);
    }

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(inputFile);
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).   BTW - do some debugging in that method along the lines of `File f = new File("."); System.out.println(f.getCanonicalPath());` and check it points to where you expect.

Comment: I'm almost positive that it has something to do with the path. What OS is this running on and are you escaping the slashes (backslashes for Windows, forward slashes otherwise)? (E.g. C:\Some Directory\file.txt is wrong. It should be **C\\:Some Directory\\file.txt)**

Comment: Also, since you're just starting off, I'd recommend using fixed a  String object for your test program instead of entering it by hand (E.g. `String file = "C:\\Some Directory\\file.txt";` would be much easier to spot a mistake in than something you enter into the console. Paths are easy enough to mess up as it is and, when you type it by hand every time, it makes it even easier to mess up. But, that's just my take on it. I don't want to discourage you from experimenting because that's how you learn.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. If you get a `FilENotFoundException`, obviously the reason is File Not Found in the given path.
If you use an IDE, path for the working directory is different from the source directory.
For example, if you are using NetBeans, your source files are inside `/src`. But your working directory (`.`) is the project directory.
In the other hand, the problem may be the thing that @Don mentioned. If you are going for a cross platform approach, you can use "`/`" in paths. It works irrespective to the OS.
Example : `String fileName = "C:/Directory/File.txt";`
And these paths are case sensitive. So make sure you use the correct case. (It won't be a problem in Windows, until you package the program.)