# FileNotFoundException when running a jar file

Tags: java, file, filenotfoundexception

I got this path `.\\src\\aee\\user\\scorePercentage.csv` . It's running when I execute this in Netbeans. But when I created a jar file, the `scorePercentage.csv` can't be found.

Comment: ..and your question is?  BTW - use the tip I describe [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16116469/418556) to discover where the 'current directory' is.  Likely it points to a different directory than you expect.

Comment: Check your jar. Is the file present. How did you create the jar. If you are doing it using netbeans, check your settings if it includes only *.class files. Check whether the path to load the file is correct.

Comment: *.class files are included,even the .csv

Comment: 1) Add @NoobUnChained (or whoever) to notify them of a new comment. 2) A resource in a Jar cannot be accessed by `File`, instead it must be accessed by `URL`.  3) Is this CSV for read only?

Comment: @Andrew - that csv file is for reading and writing

Answer (score 2):

You should either export it to the directory from which the application is running, or use Class.getResource and embed it in the jar.  If you use the `src` directory anywhere in your code, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: From one of the OP's later comments, it seems `Class.getResource(String)` is the way to go here.

Answer (score -1):

And working directory for a .jar file is `/src` directory. you can represent resources by `getClass().getResources(String);`
Ex:`getClass().getResources("/aee/user/scorePercentage.csv");`